# Add logical constraint while designing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, constraints, ssms

I have a table like below:

Student:

```
StudentId   FirstName    LastName     Grade
```

Course:

```
CourseId    Name     Desc
```

Offering

```
OfferNum     CourseId      ProfessorId
```

Student_Course_Mapping

```
OfferNum     StudentId
```

> I have a constraint which says that student can enrol only in 2
>   offering for 1 term and year.
>
> For eg: Lets say student john has enrol in Java and Python for Winter
>   term(January - April) 2020 than he cannot enrol in other courses.

I don't have any front end or anything else to restrict this. I only have been told to work with the database and apply this constraint.

Right now we are entering data manually in this table using `SSMS design view`.

So is it possible to restrict someone entering such data?

Comment: This is more of a business rule than a constraint, IMHO. You could create an after insert trigger on the `Student_Course_Mapping` to rollback the operation when the insert is attempted.

Comment: There is nothing that defines "term". As an example, a class might be offered in Spring 2020 but not Summer 2020. Perhaps that is what is meant by Offering - but then it lacks critical information.

Answer (score 0):

This type of numeric constraint between two tables is not trivial to implement.

Here are four approaches.

(1) Create a table with one row per student, term, and year.  Have two columns, one for each course.  It is not possible to have more than two with this approach.

(2) Create a user-defined function that calculates the number of courses for a student in a given term and year.  Then create a check constraint using this function.

(3) Create a with one per student, term, and year and a count of the courses for the term.  Maintain this count using a trigger and place a check constraint on the value.

(4) Maintain all the logic in the "application".  This would entail doing all inserts via a stored procedure and having the stored procedure validate the business logic.

In your case, I would probably opt for (2) as the last intrusive solution.  If you already had a table with one row per student/term/year, I would suggest (3).  It does involve a trigger (argggh!) but it also maintains useful information for other purposes.

Comment: for option 5: an ordinal not null column with a check constraint (1, 2) and a unique index on student, term, year, courseid, ordinal ? (and a unique constraint on student, term, year, courseid)

Comment: @lptr . . . That seems rather difficult to keep up-to-date if courses are deleted.